# Can't Create Appointment in Office 365 Group Calendar using EWS

Tags: c#, office365, exchangewebservices

I am trying to create appointment (not meeting)  in Office 365 Group (Unified Group) calendar using Exchange Web Service api with following C# code.

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
service.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin@officedomain.com", "pwd");
service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/Ews/Exchange.asmx");
service.PreAuthenticate = false;

Appointment appointment = new Appointment(service);
// Set the properties on the appointment object to create the appointment.
appointment.Subject = "Tennis lesson";
appointment.Body = "Focus on backhand this week.";
appointment.Start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
appointment.End = appointment.Start.AddHours(1);
appointment.Location = "Tennis club";
appointment.ReminderDueBy = DateTime.Now;
Folder rtFolder1 = Folder.Bind(service, new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, "o365group@officedomain.com"));
appointment.Save(rtFolder1.Id, SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
```

The calendar event is created successfully. But my problem is, it is created as meeting and not as appointment.
As you see in above code I didn’t add any attendee, but when I open group calendar event in OWA it shows the credential user (admin@officedomain.com) as attendee and it force me not to uncheck the option “Send an invitation to the group” as shown in below image.

[image]

Can anyone help me to overcome this problem?